# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 and dart:html Error

Tags: flutter, firebase

So I'm working with firebase, and everything was working fine, but suddenly weird exceptions started to show. I've tried everything I know and have seen others doing. I've tried `flutter clean`, `flutter upgrade`, deleted my `pubspec.lock`, and so on. This is how my Debug Console looks like :

```
   Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
lib/auth/Login.dart:1
import 'dart:html';
       ^

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flare_flutter-3.0.2/lib/flare_render_box.dart:167:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1
        SchedulerBinding.instance?.cancelFrameCallbackWithId(_frameCallbackID);
                         ^

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flare_flutter-3.0.2/lib/flare_render_box.dart:170:28: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1
          SchedulerBinding.instance?.scheduleFrameCallback(_beginFrame) ?? -1;
                           ^

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flare_flutter-3.0.2/lib/flare_render_box.dart:272:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:652:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:792:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:615:9)
<asynchronous suspension>

#4      starter (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/lib/frontend_server.dart:1433:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:10:14)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 37s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

here is my `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
name: flutter_application_6
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.5 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.20.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.6.2
  cloud_firestore: ^3.4.3
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.4
  firebase_messaging: ^12.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.0
  awesome_dialog: ^2.2.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line in `lib/auth/Login.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:html';
```